How do I save and then enter a search/replace grep expression at the colon in visual mode
If I have n e o v i m, I want neovim and I want to apply it whenever I find such occurrence (scanned OCR).
I selected the string in visual mode and then applied a search/replace expression: '<,'>s/\%V\s\%V//g which works. However, I cannot find a way to save it to a macro or key assignment such that when I make a visual selection I can repeat.

"I cannot find a way" - what have you tried? In what way did it not work? What do you expect to happen?

You could do:
vnoremap <leader>r :s/\%V\s//g<CR>

Or in lua
vim.keymap.set("v", "<leader><C-r>", ":s/\\%V\\s//g<CR>") 

If g:mapleader is set to \ or if it is not set, when you would hit \r the spaces that are part of the visual selection would be removed.

I am using neovim and lua (lazy).  Your answer, with a couple of additions into the keymap file: vim.keymap.set("v", "", ":s/\%V\s//g") works.  Thanks

Thanks for your feedback! I have updated the solution to propose the Neovim solution that you have created :-)
